# Out of so many events provided by spring - Which event is the right event to listen to cache the data for my application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my spring application i want to cache some data. To accomplish this task i implemented a listener for the event contextRefreshEvents. The only catch is that when this event will be fired by spring and how many times, because i dont want my data to be cached again.

When i went through some of the links like :  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-context-events
it is mentioned that the spring will raise this event during  "**initializing or refreshing the ApplicationContext**". Initialization is fine because this happens when we start the server and so this event will be triggered only once,  but i wanted more info about the Application context refreshing part.
When the application context will be refreshed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refreshing a context in spring various to application to application.
If you are using spring-boot then its not possible to refresh the context since it a non refreshable context.

In other cases you can if you are using Xmlbasedcontext loading. During the run time if you are altering some classes and wants to load that modified classes as apart of your running app means you can remove the existing context of that class and add the new one. so this is one part.
If you think that so many stuffs are going to change then prop you can use refresh.

And one more thing if you use refresh then it wont affect the existing @Autowired stuffs. so be careful on that.
Checkout their docs for various refreshable context before proceeding.

Comment: i am using spring boot only, then i can safely say the event "contextRefreshEvents" will be triggered only once according to your first statement.

Thats answers my question . Thank you